# wget on repository atlassian returning 404

Tags: bitbucket, wget

I have a process batch that it downloads repositories from bitbucket with `wget` command. Now, the process is fail with 404 error

```
wget   https://bitbucket.org/fwmovilidad/desplieguemanualcformation/get/SubidaPRO20FEB.tar.gz
--2022-09-30 08:48:01--  https://bitbucket.org/fwmovilidad/desplieguemanualcformation/get/SubidaPRO20FEB.tar.gz
Resolviendo bitbucket.org (bitbucket.org)... 104.192.141.1
Conectando con bitbucket.org (bitbucket.org)[104.192.141.1]:443... conectado.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 404 Not Found
2022-09-30 08:48:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlassian recently made a change where we return `404` instead of `403` code for unauthenticated users, which has caused an issue in downloading the archive from Bitbucket using wget.

The `wget` command always waits for the `403` challenge from the server before it sends the credentials to the server.
However, with the recent changes, the server initially sends the `404` status to the client and wget doesn't send credentials later on.

I have two suggestions to work around this issue:

1. To use the `--auth-no-challenge`  flag in the `wget` command as follows:

`wget --user=BitbucketUsername --password=AppPassword --auth-no-challenge https://bitbucket.org/Workspace-ID/Repo/get/master.tar.gz`

2. You can download the file using `curl` command instead:

`curl -u BitbucketUsername:AppPassword https://bitbucket.org/Workspace-ID/Repo/master.tar.gz -o master.tar.gz`